# SSH To Ubuntu through Bridged Connection

Tags: ubuntu, windows, ssh, bridge, wireless-bridge

At the moment i have a small 2 computer network that i am trying to get to work how i want.
I have a laptop which has a networking card which has wifi and Ethernet connections. This laptop is bridged with a crossover cable to my desktop which is running Ubuntu. so hence bridges the connection through the laptop to the router/modem. This is working fine and i decided that i would want to share files, So i installed smb on the Ubuntu machine and managed to connect to the windows machine using nautilus (default file manager). However from The windows laptop i am unable to SSH to the Linux machine.

I have installed on the Linux machine both openssh-server and openssh-client. Yet i still cannot receive the ssh connection. when i use putty to connect i get a msgbox saying "Network error:Connection timed out" . I manually setup the ip address, gateway, dns server etc on the Ubuntu machine to get a connection. I have the desktop (Ubuntu) set to 10.0.0.11. and the bridge connection on windows says in the status section that its ip is 10.0.0.7 through ipv4. That (10.0.0.7) is the ip i used to connect to the laptop from the Ubuntu desktop. I was wandering if there is anything i am missing or haven't setup right to allow the connection?

Comment: Check firewall settings. Also, is there an actual wireless bridge involved here? (Because that probably won't work. You can't IP bridge to a WiFi client connection. If you could, we wouldn't need WDS to extend a wireless network -- we'd just bridge.)

Comment: There is a bridge, as in: I bridged the wifi adapter and the ethernet adapter on the laptop so that both components would connect to the router. Also what is WDS? and no the firewall isn't involved. Thanx Jesse